# Generate all binary strings with n-bit?

Tags: python, recursion

I am reading a book in which following code is given-

```
def appendAtFront(x, L):
   return [x + element for element in L]

def bitStrings(n):
   if n == 0: return []
   if n == 1: return ["0", "1"]
   else:
     return (appendAtFront("0", bitStrings(n-1)) + appendAtFront("1", bitStrings(n-1)))

print(bitStrings(4))
```

Then book says "T(n)=2T(n-1)+ d, for some constant d and hence by Master theorem we get T(n)=O(2^n)"

But I think complexity should be O(n2^n) when I try to solve it making recursion tree as when we move to the bottom of the tree we are solving similar problem exponential times.

What I think should be the corrected solution

```
def bitStrings(n):
   if n == 0: return []
   if n == 1: return ["0", "1"]
   else:
     A=bitStrings(n-1)
     return (appendAtFront("0", A) + appendAtFront("1", A))

print(bitStrings(4))
```

This will give me complexity of O(2^n).

Am I missing something here?

Comment: It's invoking `bitStrings(n-1)` redundantly....

Comment: So the time complexity in book code is wrong?

Comment: What assumptions is the book making about the time complexity of `appendAtFront`?

Comment: Nothing is mentioned. That's why I am thinking equation should have been T(n)=T(n-1)+O(2^n).